# Information about Mathematical Neuroscience

Tags: soft-question, applications, advice

I would like some advices about my career. I'm an undergraduate student of math and I was looking for some interesting fields I could choose for my advanced studies. A field that caught my attention is Mathematical Neuroscience. I would like to know more precisely which are the contact points between these two disciplines and what mathematicians can do in this field. Also what mathematicals tools do I need to approach this subject, and if there's some understandable material for beginners.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Start here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_neuroscience)

Comment: You'll use a lot of statistics and probability. Make sure your computational linear algebra is good. Also make sure you can program, preferably in Python.